# garbage value while printing second Carinfo record using linkedlist in C

Tags: c, database

/*The motto of this program is to add members of the car dynamically and print them*/
whenever I am running the code, the first addition when carbase is null is getting correct but when I am trying to add more members to the linked list, the same is not getting reflected. there is no addition of the second car record and while printing the brand of the car, some garbage value is getting printed. 
It will be helpul if I get to know where I m doing a mistake and in applying the data structure concepts. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct carinfo_t
{
        char brand[100];
        char model[100];
        int year;
        float value;
        struct carinfo_t *next;
}; 

struct carinfo_t *createCarinfo(char *brand,char *model, int year,float value);
void printCarbase (struct carinfo_t *carbase);
struct carinfo_t * addCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carbase, struct carinfo_t *carinfo);
void freeCarinfo (struct carinfo_t *carinfo,char *brand,char *model);
struct carinfo_t *removeCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carbase, struct carinfo_t *carinfo);

int main()
{   
        struct carinfo_t *carbase='\0';
        struct carinfo_t *carinfo='\0';
        char choice;
        bool flag=false;
        char *brand; char *model; int year; float value;
        while(!flag)
        {

                scanf("%c",&choice);

            switch(choice)
            {
                 printf("Command a/p/q:");

                case 'a':
                    {
                        printf("Add a car:");
                        brand= (char *)malloc(100);
                        scanf("%s",brand);
                        model= (char *)malloc(100);
                        scanf("%s",model);
                        scanf("%d",&year);
                        scanf("%f",&value);
                        carinfo= (struct carinfo_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct carinfo_t));
                        carinfo->next= NULL;
                        carinfo=createCarinfo(brand,model,year,value);
                        carbase=addCarinfo(carbase,carinfo);
                        freeCarinfo(carinfo,brand,model);
                        break;
                    }
                case 'p':
                    {
                        printCarbase(carbase); 
                        break;
                    }
                case 'q':
                    {
                        flag=true;
                        exit(0);
                    }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}

struct carinfo_t *createCarinfo(char *brand, char *model, int year, float value)
 {
        struct carinfo_t *t;
        char *bbrand;
        char *bmodel;
        t= (struct carinfo_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct carinfo_t));
        bbrand= (char *)malloc(strlen(brand)+1);
        bmodel= (char *)malloc(strlen(model)+1);
        strcpy(bbrand,brand);
        strcpy(bmodel,model);
        t->year= year;
        t->value= value;
        strcpy(t->brand,bbrand);
        strcpy(t->model,bmodel);
        return (t);
}

struct carinfo_t *addCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carbase, struct carinfo_t *carinfo)
{
    struct carinfo_t *h,*t1;
    h=carbase;

    t1=(struct carinfo_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct carinfo_t));
    if(h=='\0')
    {
        t1=carinfo;
        t1->next=NULL;
        h=t1;
        h->next=t1->next;
    }

   else
   {
        t1=carinfo;
        t1=(struct carinfo_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct carinfo_t));
        t1->next=h->next;
        h->next=t1;
   }
    printCarbase(h);
    printCarbase(t1);
    return h;

}


void freeCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carinfo, char *brand, char * model)
{
   free(carinfo);
   free(brand);
   free(model);
}


void printCarbase(struct carinfo_t *carbase)
{
    struct carinfo_t *t;
    t= (struct carinfo_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct carinfo_t));
    t=carbase;
    if(t == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty list\n");
    }
    else
    {
      //printf("\n\nList elements are - \n");
      do{
        printf("-brand:%s\n",t->brand);
        printf("-model:%s\n",t->model);
        printf("-year:%d\n",t->year);
        printf("-value:%f\n",t->value);

        t = t->next;
      }while(t != NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: The initialization of `truct carinfo_t *carbase='\0'` is *invalid*. The expression `'\0'` is the null-terminator *character*, not a null pointer. The null pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: You also have *many* memory leaks. And don't actually initialize all members of the `carinfo_t` structure in your `createCarinfo` function.

Comment: Lastly, please go back you your text book or class notes, and read them again. There are so many problems with this code it's really hard to list them all.

Comment: Thanks allot. I will do so.

Comment: I have done intentionally in createCarinfo because we can't assign pointer variable to the array so

Comment: I suggest you start with thinking about what happens when you do something like `foo = malloc(...)` directly followed by `foo = somethingElse`. What happens with the original value of `foo`? Also think about this is (not!) different from e.g. `int a; a = 5; a = 7;`, what happens with the old value of `a` in the second assignment? I also suggest you [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would be very useful here I think.

Comment: thank you. will do what u said and understand the basics of it.

Comment: @SumanJain There are memory leak in `createCarinfo`, `bbrand and bmodel` are nor freed. Also I believe there is no need of declaring temp variables, you can directly do `strcpy` on struct members. This way`strcpy(t->brand,brand);` and
        `strcpy(t->model,model);`